# create an array from original array but basis on where code is running?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have three machine (each in different datacenter) in a `machines` array.

- If my shell script is running on `abc` datacenter then I want to scp files from `machineA.abc.host.com` which will be my local box. I will pick other two boxes as remote servers to copy files incase local box is down.
- If my shell script is running on `def` datacenter then I want to scp files from `machineB.def.host.com` which will be my local box. I will pick other two boxes as remote servers to copy files incase local box is down.
- If my shell script is running on `pqr` datacenter then I want to scp files from `machineC.pqr.host.com` which will be my local box. I will pick other two boxes as remote servers to copy files incase local box is down.

Below is my script but I believe it can be done in much better way instead of using three different variables and then having three scp staetments seprated by or:

```
machines=(machineA.abc.host machineB.def.host.com machineC.pqr.host.com)

case $(hostname -f) in
    *abc.host.com)
        local_server=("${machines[0]}")
        primary_remote==("${machines[1]}")
        secondary_remote==("${machines[2]}")
        ;;
    *def.host.com)
        local_server=("${machines[1]}")
        primary_remote==("${machines[2]}")
        secondary_remote==("${machines[0]}")
        ;;
    *pqr.host.com)
        local_server=("${machines[2]}")
        primary_remote==("${machines[0]}")
        secondary_remote==("${machines[1]}")        
        ;;
    *) echo "unknown host: $(hostname -f), exiting." >&2 && exit 1 ;;
    # ?
esac

export local="$local_server"
export remote1="$primary_remote"
export remote2="$secondary_remote"

copyFiles() {
  el=$1
  primsec=$2
  # can we just iterate from for loop instead of writing three scp statements?
  (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@"$local":/proc/data/abc_187_"$el"_111_8.data "$primsec"/.) ||   (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@"$remote1":/proc/data/abc_187_"$el"_111_8.data "$primsec"/.) ||   (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@"$remote2":/proc/data/abc_187_"$el"_111_8.data "$primsec"/.)

}
export -f copyFiles

# using gnu parallel here to call above methods parallely
```

Now as you can see I have three scp statements one for local box, other for remote1 and remote2. What I am thinking is maybe we can get rid of these three scp statements and instead store hostnames (in a particular order, first index can be local box and other two can be remote) in an array and then iterate that array from a for loop and just write one scp statement?

```
for p in "$machines"; do scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@"$p":/proc/data/abc_187_"$el"_111_8.data "$primsec"/. && break; done > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If this is possible then how can I reshuffle `machines` array accordingly or maybe create a different array then with right machine in them at proper index?

**Update:**

Somehow my for loop inside that function is not running at all:

```
copyFiles() {
  local el=$1
  local primsec=$2
  local remote_file="/proc/data/abc_187_${el}_111_8.data"
  for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    echo "$host"
    echo "scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "goldy@$host:$remote_file" "$primsec"/." && break
  done
}
export hosts
export -f copyFiles

parallel -j 5 copyFiles {} $proc::: ${pro[@]} &
parallel -j 5 copyFiles {} $data::: ${seco[@]} &
wait
echo "everything copied"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: it uses

- an associative array to hold the "local" machine names
- an array to hold the sequence of hosts for scp
- a for loop to iterate over the possible hosts, and break after the first successful scp

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A machines=(
    [abc]=machineA.abc.host.com
    [def]=machineB.def.host.com 
    [pqr]=machineC.pqr.host.com
)

IFS=. read -a host_parts < <(hostname -f)

case "${host_parts[1]}" in
    abc) hosts=( "${machines[abc]}" "${machines[def]}" "${machines[pqr]}" ) ;;
    def) hosts=( "${machines[def]}" "${machines[pqr]}" "${machines[abc]}" ) ;;
    pqr) hosts=( "${machines[pqr]}" "${machines[abc]}" "${machines[def]}" ) ;;
    *) echo "unknown host: $(hostname -f), exiting." >&2; exit 1 ;;
esac

copyFiles() {
    local el=$1
    local primsec=$2
    local remote_file="/proc/data/abc_187_${el}_111_8.data"
    for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
        scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "goldy@$host:$remote_file" "$primsec"/. && break
    done
}

export hosts
export -f copyFiles
```

Comment: yeah great suggestion. I tried running this on a box and it went to last echo statement and printed out `unknown host` line. Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: I have some box in this format: `techTee-962.proc.abc.host.com` and some box in this format `yetrea.abc.host.com` so if we pick datacenter basis on index from starting then it may not work bcoz of machine names we have. Is there any way to pick index from end. Meaning first index will be `com`, second `host` and third will always be `abc`? Is this possible or any other better idea?

Comment: Not in a position to check right now but try `${host_parts[-3]}` to get the 3rd last word

Comment: yeah that works fine.. thanks! I noticed very weird thing - `for` loop inside that `copyFiles` function doesn't run. None of my echo statements are getting printed out. Any idea why? But if I copy that for loop and run it before and after `copyFiles` function then it works fine. Not sure what is wrong here? I have updated the question with code that I have after `export`.

Comment: put a `declare -p hosts` in the function to see what's in that array while the function executes. Also, before the function is called. It seems that array is empty, so the for loop has zero iterations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169782/discussion-between-user5447339-and-glenn-jackman).